# How to use OnClickListener for items in AlertDialog Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin, android-camera, android-alertdialog, android-storage

So i get this java code about AlertDialog:

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder= new AlertDialog.Builder(context:this);
builder.setTitle("Pick Image")
     .setItems(options, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){
          @Override
          public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which){
            if(which==0){
             if(checkCameraPermission())pickFromcamera();
             else requestCameraPermission(); 
            } else{
              if(checkStoragePermission()) pickFromGallery();
              else requestStoragePermission();
             }
    }
}
```

And i try to use this in my Kotlin project, so i change it a bit. My code look like:

```
val options: Array<String> = arrayOf("Kamera","Gallery")
        val builder= AlertDialog.Builder(this)
        builder.setTitle("Pilih Gambar")
            .setItems(options,DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){
                @Override
                fun onClick(dialog: DialogInterface, which: Int){
                    if(which==0){
                        if(checkCameraPermission()){
                            pickFromCamera()
                        }
                        else{
                            requestCameraPermission()
                        }
                    }
                    else{
                        if(checkStoragePermission()){
                            pickFromGallery()
                        }
                        else{
                            requestStoragePermission()
                        }
                    }
                }
            })
            .show()
```

But i get this error : `Expected 2 parameters of types DialogInterface!, Int` at my setItems. Why is this happen? What did i do wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You combined Java with Kotlin. Try writing it like this with your logic inside of the lambda assuming you're trying to do it in Kotlin.

```
    val options: Array<String> = arrayOf("Kamera","Gallery")
        val builder= AlertDialog.Builder(requireContext())
        builder.setTitle("Pilih Gambar").setItems(options) { dialog, which ->
            if(which==0){
                    if(checkCameraPermission()){
                        pickFromCamera()
                    }
                    else{
                        requestCameraPermission()
                    }
                }
                else{
                    if(checkStoragePermission()){
                        pickFromGallery()
                    }
                    else{
                        requestStoragePermission()
                    }
                }
        }
        .show()
```

Comment: So, i use OnClickListener inside the setItems?and for dialog and which doesn't it need to include the data type?

Comment: Not sure what you mean, but I added the logic from your original code for clarity

Comment: I understand, it turns out that my error was in migrating java to kotlin. thanks for the answer